# Swift - What is the best approach for managing Static Strings and Constants (like URLs, IDs, Image names etc)

Tags: ios, xml, static, plist, constants

Right now we are working with a flat file called Constants.swift with all the constants simply written there or inside a simple enum.
Is this a good approach? is there a better way (like saving a Plist or parsing an XML file)?

If Plists are the way to go, how do i read from them properly without making it overkill with a lot of code just to read from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think using an enum is a good approach, like this:

```
enum Constants {
    enum SubConstants {
        static let Constant1234 = "Hello sir!"
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
print(Constants.SubConstants.Constant1234)
```

A plist could be a good approach if you have a server which gives you the constants depending on Country, users and so on.

If you want to use the plist you can follow [this](http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/) guide.

**UPDATE:**

How Adnan pointed out, you shouldn't use enum to store the constants since it is not a best practice, instead you should use a struct:

```
struct Constants {
    struct SubConstants {
        static let Constant1234 = "Hello sir!"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using enum instead of struct (both with static variables)?

Comment: @Kubba with a struct you can instantiate it like this: let constants = Constants() and to avoid this you use an enum which doesn't allow it

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa although what you have suggest is legit in swift, but this is not best parctice, Enums are very particular data structure which is used to hold different entries of same data type, and by definition, enum should have cases (I am talking about semantics, not the syntax here) and who knows in future Swift add compile time error for enums without cases.  For namespace constants Structs should be used, and if only reason you are using enum that we can not initilize them then you can achive same by adding a private empty init in struct.

Comment: Also if someone just initilize it no problem, because he/she can't use it and cimpiler will give compile time 'Unused variable or constant'

Comment: So what IS the most suggested practice for this? structs? plist? im confused :P

Comment: @MarkosDarkin the best way is using enum/struct.. what adnan says makes sense, you can use either enum or struct..if you don't care of the possibility to instantiate a struct so you can use it

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to answer :) appreciate it

Comment: @AdnanAftab you should add your comment as answer - it describes everything and in my opinion it should be accepted